# How to secure/encrypt credit card data in .NET Core REST API Http method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a HTTP Post method call on my DIY experiment payment gateway like below:

```
public IActionResult PostPayment([FromBody][Required] GatewayPostDto data) {

}
```

where `GatewayPostDto` has various payment information like credit card number, currency, cvv & so on like below:

```
public class GatewayPostDto {
        [Required, Display(Name = "Card Holder Name")]
        public string CardHolderName { get; set; }

        [Required, CreditCard, Display(Name = "Card Number")]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Expiration Month"), Range(0, 12)]
        public long? CardExpiryMonth { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Expiration Year"), Range(2021, 2100)]
        public long? CardExpiryYear { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "CVC Security Code"),
         RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "CVC security code can only contain numbers")]
        public string CardCvc { get; set; }
    }
```

I know the method above to store sensitive credit card details **are bad**.

How do I store the credit card details exposed from HTTP Post method call?

Is it possible? If yes, could you provide me an example?

P/S: I build the HTTP Post call method with swagger which looks like below:
[image]

Comment: You're walking down a rabbit hole here. The only reason you "secure" something is because you _know_ what an attack vector could be, and you try to mitigate it by making that attack vector harder to execute. So, what security attack vectors are you trying to mitigate?

Comment: @gunr2171, since the credit card number is exposed in the DTO - as you can see in the `curl` statement from the swagger, is it possible for anyone to eavesdrop it? What is the best practice to save the credit card data in the DTO?

Comment: "is it possible for anyone to eavesdrop it" if you use HTTP, absolutely. If you use HTTPS, probably not but it's possible. "Web Security" is a very large topic.

Comment: @gunr2171, from Rest API point of view, is there other better way to store the credit card data in a DTO or my method above is the only way?